# Extract values between '\r'

Tags: r, string

I have got a string which is like:

`"\r Joel Corry feat. MNEK\r Head & Heart\r "`

I want to create a `df` with two columns with the values of above string between "\r":

| interpret | song |
| --- | --- |
| Joel Corry feat. MNEK | Head & Heart |

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `strsplit`:

```
x <- "\r Joel Corry feat. MNEK\r Head & Heart\r"    

df$interpret <- trimws(strsplit(x, split = "\\r")[[1]])[2]
df$song<- trimws(strsplit(x, split = "\\r")[[1]])[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
dat = data.table(raw_string =  c(
  "\r Joel Corry feat. MNEK\r Head & Heart\r ",
  "\r Intepret 2\r Song 2\r ",
  "\r Intepret 3\r Song 3\r ")
)
dat[,c("interpret","song"):= tstrsplit(str_remove_all(raw_string,"(^\r\\s?)|(\r\\s?$)"),"\r")][]
```

Output:

```
                                   raw_string             interpret          song
                                       <char>                <char>        <char>
1: \r Joel Corry feat. MNEK\r Head & Heart\r  Joel Corry feat. MNEK  Head & Heart
2:                  \r Intepret 2\r Song 2\r             Intepret 2        Song 2
3:                  \r Intepret 3\r Song 3\r             Intepret 3        Song 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `extract` to define a regex that (i) exhaustively describes the string but (ii) wraps into capture groups `(...)` only what you want to extract into the two new columns (and thereby effectively removes anything not inside a capture group). Note that `\` needs to escaped by double backslash (in R):

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(str,
          into = c("interpret", "song"),
          regex = "\\\r (.*)\\\r (.*)\\\r")
              interpret         song
1 Joel Corry feat. MNEK Head & Heart
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  str = "\r Joel Corry feat. MNEK\r Head & Heart\r "
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below another possibility using the `stringr` library

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(stringr)

setNames(as.data.frame(str_extract_all(my_text, "(?<=\\r ).+", simplify = TRUE)), c("interpret", "song"))
```

- Output

```r
#>               interpret         song
#> 1 Joel Corry feat. MNEK Head & Heart
```

- Data

```r
my_text <- "\r Joel Corry feat. MNEK\r Head & Heart\r "
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>